# Magento - get children of quote item

Tags: magento

I am attempting to retrieve the quote items that have a particular parent_item_id

I actually have an instance of the parent quote item which I retrieved like so:

```
$parentQuoteItem = Mage::getModel("sales/quote_item")->load($quoteItemId);
```

How can I extract the children of this quote item?

I have tried calling the getChildren() method but unfortunately its giving an empty array:

```
$parentQuoteItem->getChildren()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

---------------**UPDATE**-----------------------------

I kinda solved the issue with the following code:

```
$aChildQuoteItems = Mage::getModel("sales/quote_item")
                                ->getCollection()
                                ->setQuote($mQuote)
                                ->addFieldToFilter("parent_item_id", $quoteItemId);
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what do you need exactly. Look on $parentQuoteItem->getOptions(), does it return what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately it returned an empty array :S ... thanks anways mate. I solved the issue in another manner. See updated question

Comment: Can you please provide your answer to you own question as a answer and not inline it in your question? That would make it possible to vote it up.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to load the quote first before calling getparent/child on the item...

```
$parent_quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->load($quote_id);
$q_item = $quote->getItemById('q_item_id_looking_for')->getChildren();
// do something with them...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried above but didn't work for me. Here is how I resolved this:

```
<?php foreach(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>

                <?php
                    if($_item->getParentItemId()) {
                        $parentQuote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote_item")->load($_item->getParentItemId());
                        $qty = $parentQuote->getQty();
                    } else {
                        $qty = $_item->getQty();
                    }
                ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```

Above is helpful if your Bundle product is of fixed price type.

Answer (score -2):

not Loving that solution you have too much, why not:

```
?php foreach(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>

            <?php
                if ($item->getHasChildren()){

                    $qty = $_item->getQty();
                }
            ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain why your answer is better?

Comment: @KatieK His answer is better because he doesn't load a new quote item wich means less stress on the database.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. Also its quite bad template syntax.